# QT's fromTime_t from QDateTime doesn't work

Tags: c++, qt

I tried using QDateTime's fromTime_t as follows:

```
QDateTime t;
time_t elapsedTime;
t.fromTime_t(elapsedTime);
```

The result is that nothing is assigned to the QDateTime object. 
However, using the function setTime_t does work (this one isn't static).
Is something going on here I'm missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`fromTime_t` is static and returns a `QDateTime`, so you have to use it like this:

```
    time_t elapsedTime;
    QDateTime t(QDateTime::fromTime_t(elapsedTime));
```

or you can do

```
    time_t elapsedTime;
    QDateTime t;
    t.setTime_t(elapsedTime);
```

Comment: Just update: this method is now obsolete. This should be used instead https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdatetime.html#fromSecsSinceEpoch

Answer (score 3):

Your code doesn't use the static function correctly.  Try this instead:

```
time_t elapsedTime;
...
QDateTime t = QDateTime::fromTime_t(elapsedTime);
```